# What is the difference between "мои" , "моя", "мой"?

Tags: узус

My curiosity I have started learning Russian. While i read some articles they specified same meaning for different word. Can any one clarify my doubt and guide me in right path?

Comment: please tend to ask one question per post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мои, моя, мой - are just conjugation of Мое; they are plural, feminine, 
masculine respectively.
A full table of those conjugations you can see [wiktionary, мой](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9)

It is one of the possessive pronouns - мой, твой, свой, ваш, наш, его, её, их
It just has to be memorized and having a small card where they are written helps.
[image]

(source of the picture, as I found it, is one of pinterest, but I can't link to it, because I need to have account there, which I do not, and the link will be useless for not pinterest users)

Дом - is just a construction, house
Дома - mean at home, or plural form of Дом. The difference is in context and emphasis.

- Дóма - at home
- Домá - homes